# How to return Equal Parts R to G to B in PHP?

Tags: php, colors, rgb

Is there a function or way to calculate RGB percentages based on a color in a way that would output in "1 part blue + 2 parts red"

for example hex value: #320032

R: 50 G: 0 B: 50

H: 300 S:100 B:20

How do I convert those numbers into "equal parts" phrasing?
IE: 1 Parts Red + 1 Parts Blue + 1 Parts Black (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to use a percent, like .5 (for 2 parts)  and .25 (for 1 part) and multiply it by 255.  I'm not exactly sure what your goal is.

Comment: The goal would be to out put a color mixing recipe base on Red Green Blue Black and White

Answer (score 0):

First, convert to RGB if it isn't already.

Then, for example for `#400080` you can say "64 parts red + 128 parts blue".

Then calculate the greatest common demoniator of the numbers you get (simple math here)

Divide all the numbers by that GCD.

In this example, the GCD is 64 so the result is "1 part red + 2 parts blue".